# How do i get X Axis to start from 0 and update each second instead of using the current time(DateTime)?

Tags: c#, xaml, livecharts

I'm trying to create like a measuring system that can measure a value on Y axis and time on X axis with LiveCharts.

I've used [Constant Changes](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Constant%20Changes) as a base to create my graph but I want my X Axis to start from 0 seconds instead of the current time like they do in the example. I've tried [How to make the x Axis to start on 0 and have a step of 2 seconds, instead of staring on a second the program started, using Livecharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695549/how-to-make-the-x-axis-to-start-on-0-and-have-a-step-of-2-seconds-instead-of-st#new-answer?newreg=65990256287346c182a43af3b9099a7a) but I couldn't get it to work with my program. I want to do the same thing they did in thread linked above but can't get it to work.

[My Output/ How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Pm5.jpg)

Code Behind:

```
        public void init()
        {
            var mapper = Mappers.Xy<ValueRandomizerForTest>().X(model => 
             model.DateTime.Ticks).Y(model => model.Valuefordate);
            Charting.For<ValueRandomizerForTest>(mapper);
            ChartValues = new ChartValues<ValueRandomizerForTest>();
            DateTimeFormatter = value => new 
                 DateTime((long)value).ToString("ss");
            AxisStep = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks;

            AxisUnit = TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
            SetAxisLimits(DateTime.Now);


        }


public void read()
        {


            var r = new Random();

            while (isreading)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(550);
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                var test = now.Second;


                _trend = r.Next(1, 100);

                if(ChartValues.Count == 0)
                {


                }

                ChartValues.Add(new ValueRandomizerForTest
                {
                    DateTime = now,
                    Valuefordate = _trend
                });


                SetAxisLimits(now);

                //lets only use the last 150 values
                if (ChartValues.Count > 150)
                {
                    ChartValues.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }



        }
        public void SetAxisLimits(DateTime now)
        {

            AxisMax = now.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks; //Axis is moving 1 second ahead
            AxisMin = now.Ticks - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks; 
        }
```

ValuerandomizerFortest Class:

```
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
        public double Valuefordate { get; set; }



        public double AxisStep { get; set; }

        public double AxisUnit { get; set; }


           private double _axisMax;

           private double _axisMin;


        public double AxisMax
        {

            get
            {
                return _axisMax
            }

            set
            {
                _axisMax = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("AxisMax");
            }
        }
        public double AxisMin
        {
            get { return _axisMin; }
            set
            {
                _axisMin = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("AxisMin");
            }
        }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDemo.Views.GraphViewer"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFDemo.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="GraphViewer" Height="700" Width="950">
    <Grid >
        <Grid Margin="759,10,10,588.4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.51,0.526">
            <Button Content="Random"
                Margin="6"
                Padding="6"
                Command="{Binding randomer}">

            </Button>

        </Grid>
        <!--<Grid Height="80" Width="200" Margin="50, -20,600,500">
            -->
        <!--<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding list}" Margin="-32,-10,32,20">
                -->
        <!--<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    -->
        <!--<DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">

                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>-->
        <!--
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>-->
        <!--
            </ComboBox>-->

        <!--<Button Content="Updater"
                    Command="{Binding ClickCommand}">


            </Button>-->
        <!--

        </Grid>-->
        <Grid Height="500" Width="940" Margin="4,100,0,28.4">



            <lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Row="1" AnimationsSpeed="0:0:0.3" Hoverable="False" DataTooltip="{x:Null}">
                <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                    <lvc:LineSeries Values="{Binding ChartValues}" 
                                PointGeometry="{x:Null}" 
                                LineSmoothness="1"
                                StrokeThickness="6" 
                                Stroke="#F34336"
                                Fill="Transparent"/>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                    <lvc:Axis x:Name="XAxis" LabelFormatter="{Binding DateTimeFormatter}" 
                          MaxValue="{Binding AxisMax}" 
                          MinValue="{Binding AxisMin}"
                          Unit="{Binding AxisUnit}">
                        <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                            <lvc:Separator Step="{Binding AxisStep}" />
                        </lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    </lvc:Axis>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            </lvc:CartesianChart>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Should it be: AxisMin = 0  ? (inside SetAxisLimits() )

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your comment. Well it shouldn't work that way because the the code still needs to know how to update the values because its in real time. I should have put in a Gif of my project but I don't know how to make one. But imagine that the picture i supplied above moves forward in the X axis and as it moves forward the previous values, in this case the current time(in seconds) gets removed and new current time get added to the X axis. So by simply setting it to 0 wont let the project know how to properly update the value. Nvm I can't post images yet. But i'll link it instead.

Comment: Ok, now I see.
The code in your question does not include the answer in your link.
As said in the link, you should save the first DateTime aside, and always subtract that value from the curernt time:

Comment: Hey I tried doing what he did in the example but I have to set AxisLimits in init before I can reuse AxisLimit in read(). What am i suppose to put in the Axislimit in init()? Thats where im struggling. I changed my mapper to             var mapper = Mappers.Xy<ValueRandomizerForTest>().X(model => model.Time.Seconds).Y(model => model.Valuefordate);

And Created a TimeSpan Test to fill in my first AxisLimits but its not working.
SetAxisLimits(Test);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments inline:

```
    private long startTimeTicks;
    public void init()
    {
        var mapper = Mappers.Xy<ValueRandomizerForTest>().X(model => 
         model.DateTime.Ticks).Y(model => model.Valuefordate);
        Charting.For<ValueRandomizerForTest>(mapper);
        ChartValues = new ChartValues<ValueRandomizerForTest>();
        DateTimeFormatter = value => new 
             DateTime((long)value).ToString("ss");
        AxisStep = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks;

        AxisUnit = TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;

        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        startTimeTicks = currentTime.Ticks; // store start time
        SetAxisLimits(currentTime);
    }

    public void read()
    {
        var r = new Random();

        while (isreading)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(550);
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var test = now.Second;

            _trend = r.Next(1, 100);

            if(ChartValues.Count == 0)
            {
            }

            ChartValues.Add(new ValueRandomizerForTest
            {
                DateTime = now - new TimeSpan(startTimeTicks),
                Valuefordate = _trend
            });

            SetAxisLimits(now);

            //lets only use the last 150 values
            if (ChartValues.Count > 150)
            {
                ChartValues.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetAxisLimits(DateTime now)
    {
        long offsetTicks = now.Ticks - startTimeTicks; // compute offset ticks from program start (at call from init() this calculation will be equal to 0)
        AxisMin = Math.Max(offsetTicks - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks, 0);
        AxisMax = AxisMin  + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6).Ticks; // Set max according to min
    }
```

Comment: Hello ! Thank you so much for helping! DateTime = now - new DateTime(startTimeTicks) is this suppose to be DateTime = now - new Timespan(starTimeTicks) ? Because i get an error if i dont change it to timespan and even when i change it to Timespan. For some reason my graph doesn't move in the X axis but only in the Y Axis. In other words it simply stays put in 1 spot and moves up and down while my graph as a whole moves forwards with time(with the line). Any idea  what it could be ? [It looks like this](https://imgur.com/a/HFLg0XC). And again thank you!

Comment: Nvm I fixed it! I even put startTimerTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks in read function so that the graph always starts at 0. Thank you so much for your help!

 One last question. Could you explain what AxisMin and AxisMax do in more detail?

Comment: You're right, I changed DateTime to TimeSpan. In SetAxisLimits(), we simply subtract the starting time from the current time (now). So let's say the program starts at time = 5. When SetAxisLimits() is called from init() we have current time = 5, start time = 5, so Min = 5 - 5 = 0, and Max will always be Min+6, so Max = 0 + 6 = 6. Then, each time the SetAxisLimits() is called from read(), Min will increase as time goes on, so if current time (now) = 15 then Min = 15 - 5 = 10, Max = 10 + 6 = 16.